# visual studio take too much time to open project once closed

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Community. Problem is when I start VS2015 it start quickly but when I open website project then it takes too much time apprx (30-60 mins) to open particular code file (Only for first time). Once it loads then it works normally. How do I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's very difficult to give an correct answer without more details as there might be a lot of things that can happen but I suggest you check the logs from [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx).

[image]

It will log all the events that happening in your OS.

After gathering the logs you need to go through them (try to filter them - there might be a LOT of them) and check for some indications of WAIT operation.

Maybe some network operation is time-outing (but 30-60 min is quite huge timeout) or some IO operation.